# Python - Stop infinite loop with yield and then redirect

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to stop an infinite while loop that passes frames from camera feed using yield function but also passes a confirmation label ("confirmation") if the right person was identified in the camera during the identification. So I have written an if statement that checks is confirmation is not equal to "notfound", and if so it means its a person and I need to redirect somewhere, in this examples - home page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, redirect, url_for
import cv2
import numpy as np
from camera2 import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

light_on = False

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def home():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/recognition', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def recognition():
    return render_template('recognition.html')

def gen(camera2):
    while True:
        confirmation, frame = camera2.get_frame()
        print(confirmation)
        # yield ('--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + '\r\n\r\n')
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
        if confirmation != "notfound":
            return redirect(url_for("home")) 

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("localhost", 5050, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

But whenever I try to do so I get an error message:

```
"Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being"
RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

I would appreciate any help or advice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, this may help some one...

```
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(function):    
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper():
        if not os.path.isdir(audioPath):
            return ""
        return function()
    return wrapper

@app.route('/playaudio')
@my_decorator           # this avoid infinity loop
def playaudio():
    def generate():
        data = ""
        if os.path.isdir(audioPath):
            for audioPath in filesAudios:
                data=subprocess.check_output(['cat',audioPath])
                yield data      # ifinity loop if audioPath do not exist
        return data
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='audio/mp3')
```